# What is the expression you use to describe that the person not just talks and gives promises, but makes actions too?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

In Russian we have a phrase, mostly used in memes, like “like a Leo Tolstoy you speak, but in fact you’re just a d**k” (meaning that you only talk beautifully but when it comes to actions you do nothing or don’t keep the promises.
I need to translate a phrase  “Like a Leo Tolstoy we speak, and in actions we’re Leo Tolstoy”, but used in English-speaking culture (or something stylistically close to it). Is there anything similar to it that sounds naturally?

Comment: *Stick to your guns* or *strong-willed*.

Comment: a bullshit artist, we say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several expressions come to mind:

> He/she walks the talk.

This means a person acts in the same way that they promise to act, or that they encourage others to act.

> - He's a man of his word.
> - She's a woman of her word.

<sup>A gender-neutral form "They're a person of their word" is possible, but I've never encountered it and it may not be understood. It sounds strange to me, but maybe that needs to change!</sup>

This means a person lives up to their promises, i.e. they do what they promise to do.

> I say what I mean and mean what I say.

This means I'm direct and honest.

> He/she leads by example.

This means a person acts the way they want others to act, thereby encouraging them to act in the same way.

Comment: “I say what I mean and mean what I say” sounds like something we need. Thank you for your help!